# Delay in message archiving for Monitoring Service plugin

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using the Monitoring service plugin to save one-to-one chats in the db (mysql). But I observe that there is some delay of about 1 minute between the time when message is received and when it gets stored in the db.

In case if user refreshes the page means the latest messages are not displayed.

How to avoid this delay?

Comment: Monitor service Plugin is not designed for that. Look here: https://igniterealtime.jiveon.com/thread/42738